# Javascript Stack value display

Tags: javascript

I have the below code inside a function

```
document.getElementById('textFromUser').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById("displayForward").value=stackforward+"\n"
valCurrent = value;
```

The "`displayForward`" is a textarea. Array items displayed in that textarea need to be seperated by a break (create a column rather than row with commas).

The page has a user input box where the user enters values (letters or numbers). Then the values get pushed to a stack and displayed in that textarea as outputs. Now the problem is that they are displayed in one row like this: v,w,x,y,z....i.e. my code still displays items in a row seperated by commas.

Whether what I need to do is to get them displayed in a column format without commas:
v
w
x
y
z

Going round in circles with this, could somebody help me fix the above please?

Comment: `stackforward` is what, an array? If so see Craig's answer, otherwise please provide more detail.

Comment: yep thats right, sorry should have put that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you had a mis-spelling in there too which I have corrected.
Try the below:

```
document.getElementById('textFromUser').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById("displayForward").value=stackforward.join("\n")
valCurrent = value;
```

hope that helps

Comment: Is stackforward a array variable?

Answer (score 0):

If `stackforward` is a `string` then try

```
document.getElementById('textFromUser').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById("displayForward").value+=stackforward+"\n";
valCurrent = value;
```

If `stackforward` is an `array` then try

```
document.getElementById('textFromUser').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById("displayForward").value=stackforward.join("\n");
valCurrent = value;
```